# How to automate a webpage in Google chrome using powershell

Tags: powershell

while navigating to the url , i have different buttons and i want to automate the click on all the buttons and also fetch some data into a file and send email with attachment if something fails  using powershell script. I just started writing the script but unable to proceed further. Please suggest.

Code:

```
$ie=Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList "abc.aspx"
$ie.Document.getElementsByName('').click( )
```

Error:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:2 char:2

Comment: I didn't understand your problem correctly but I can advise you to try Tampermonkey, which is an extension. By using that you can automate browser using JavaScript and DOM very easily. You can download it from here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en

Comment: I think you misunderstand why people usually use `$ie` variable for website manipulation. `$ie` stands for `Internet Explorer` and can operate on websites because of its built-in object `InternetExplorer.Application` that can be added to `$ie` like `$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'` but Google Chrome has no such object. You are also misusing `Start-Process`. If you assign `Start-Process` to a variable, it will wait for the thing it started to close then get information like its exit code. You cannot actively do stuff in an application using `Start-Process`

Comment: To see some info on how to navigate the internet with IE check out https://westerndevs.com/simple-powershell-automation-browser-based-tasks/

Answer (score 1):

You are combining Powershell with Javascript.
The variable $ie is empty since you didnt use -PassThru, but even if you did it would not return the content of the website because chrome.exe does not do that.

You can however use Invoke-Webrequest to get content of a website:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "google.com"
```

Then you can use the $response object:

```
$response.ParsedHTML.getElementsByName('test').click()
```